# How to start R regression at specific value

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I need to find a regression in R which has the form of

```
lm(Binary_value ~ Age, data=dataframe)
```

But my age variable starts at 15 yrs old so I'm not interested in ages that are less than 14. How can I specify that I only want my regression to be accurate at the age point of 15 and not worry about smaller values? I tried it this way:

`lm(Binary_value ~ Age, data=dataframe)`

But I get nonsense results for higher ages.

Comment: Do your data have ages below 15? If so yoou can use the `sub set` argument, `lm(Binary_value~Agge, dataframe, subset = Age >= 15)`.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

First things first, remember that R is case-sensitive, so the function would look like `lm`, not `LM`. I edited your question to fix that. Second, a regression only includes data that is available for prediction. It will not magically make up 14 data points if they are not already present, so there is no issue there. However, the regression line will not map to just => 15 years old because it uses the model coefficients to draw an intercept. An example below with fake data:

```
#### Create Fake Data ####
set.seed(123)
x <- 15:100 # use these numbers for age
age <- sample(x, # using x
              size=1000, # sample 1000 times
              replace=T) # sample with replacement
outcome <- age * .60 + rnorm(n=1000,sd=15) # make fake outcome variable
df <- data.frame(age,outcome)

#### Fit Data ####
fit <- lm(outcome ~ age, data = df)
summary(fit)
plot(age,outcome)
abline(fit,
       col = "red")
```

You will see that the regression line, despite only including 15, will still draw to the left where there is no data. This is because the intercept is a conditional value based on the coefficients.

[image]

**P.S. I used a normal Gaussian regression for this example because you used the `lm` function in your question, but included a binary response. For a logistic regression, the rationale would be the same, but it would use `glm` instead.**